Проблема с Attribute Error
Писал код который будет читать и выводить совпадения из xlsx файла, но возникла ошибка, я не совсем понял что нужно сделать поэтому обращаюсь к вам.
Код:
import openpyxl

# Укажите путь к вашему файлу XLSX
file_path = 'part1.xlsx'

# Открываем файл XLSX
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

# Введите значение, которое вы хотите найти
search_value = input('Введите значение для поиска: ')

# Поиск и вывод совпадений
found = False
for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    for cell in row:
        if isinstance(cell.value, int) and search_value in cell.value:
            print(f"Найдено совпадение в ячейке {cell.coordinate}: {cell.value}")
            found = True
        elif isinstance(cell.value, (int, float)) and search_value in str(cell.value):
            print(f"Найдено совпадение в ячейке {cell.coordinate}: {cell.value}")
            found = True

if not found:
    print("Совпадений не найдено.")

# Закрываем файл XLSX
workbook.close()

ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "C:\Users\zisho\Documents\test\test.py", line 17, in <module>                                                                                                              
    if isinstance(cell.value, int) and search_value in cell.value:                                                                                                                  
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'


замени cell.value на cell
